# how can i animate the appearance and disappearance of my UICollectionView header cells

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uicollectionviewlayout, collectionview

I am trying to animate the appearance and disappearance of my `UICollectionView` header cells.  My header cells are added in `viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind`.  From what I have researched I think I need to subclass my `collectionViewFlowLayout` and do the animations there.  I tried subclassing and added the following lines to my `viewDidLoad` of the collectionView's **viewController**:

```
let layout = chatCollectionViewFlowLayout()
chatCollectionView.setCollectionViewLayout(layout, animated: true)
```

however when I did this I no longer see my header cells and the `viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind` is not being called.  This is my first time subclassing my `collectionViewFlowLayout`.  Can somebody please help me know where I went wrong and secondly what I need to do in the subclass to animate only the disappearance of my header cell?  Thanks.  Also would there be an easier way to do this without subclassing?  I just want a simple default fade out.

Comment: okay, I figured out one part.  the reason my header was not appearing when i subclassed the flowLayout was because I also needed to again define the size of the header cell as it was no longer being taken from storyboard.  So I just added the following line in viewDidLoad:  layout.headerReferenceSize = CGSizeMake(chatCollectionView.frame.size.width, 40)